# how to get data in angular2 from response which returns an object in the backend?

Tags: c#, angular

I have rest api that returns rows (which is total number of records)
and clients ( which is the list of objects). I want to subscribe to the response.

```
return Ok(new {rows=count,clients=list});
```

If the response is  return Ok(clients});
I can just do like the below 
Angular2 :

```
private clients: Client[];
this.clientService.read().subscribe(
      clients=> this.clients=clients,
```

How can I read if the response is an object in Angular2.
I want to understand how can I access an object with multiple parameters in a subscribe method

Comment: If your question is *"how do I access object properties in JavaScript?"*, I would strongly encourage you to learn the very basics of the tools you're trying to use. If not, please [edit] to clarify what the problem is; give a [mcve].

Comment: You should also add implementation of `this.clientService.read()` method.

Comment: I want to understand how can I access an object with multiple parameters in a subscribe method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.clientService.read().subscribe( resp => 
  this.clients = resp.json().clients;
}
```

And clients from the API must have the same format as Client class.

Comment: if your API does not return a JSON, try this this.clients = resp.clients;

Comment: Thanks that helps

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know what your ClientService does. I suggest you use the newish [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http). One possible implementation could be:

```
interface Client {
    name: string;
    etc...
}

interface ClientList {
    rows: number;
    clients: Client[];
}


@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  read(): Observable<ClientList> {
    return this.http.get<ClientList>('/api/clients');
  }
}
```

Then in your component, you would have this:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    clients: Client[];

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.clientService.read().subscribe(clientList => this.clients = clientList.clients);
    }
}
```

And in your component html you can use the clients. To print a debug JSON representation of the clients:

```
{{ clients | json }}
```

I think this leaks memory though, since you subscribe and never unsubscribe.
A better way is to let angular take care of the subscribing and unsubscribing using the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Your component would instead have an observable property like so:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    clients$: Observable<Client[]>;

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.clients$ = this.clientService.read().map(clientList => clientList.clients);
    }
}
```

Notes:
The name `clients$` ends with a `$` - this is a convention to indicate it's an observable and is something lots of people do when using observables.

The `map()` call comes [Rxjs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and get rids of the rows and clients property so you only have your array since that's what you seem to want to do.

Then in your template, you can use something like this:
`{{ clients$ | async | json }}`

The `| async` part will take care of subscribing to your Observable and will unsubscribe when your component will be destroyed. It also automatically checks for detection when something happens, calling [markForCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markForCheck) which mean you can use the [OnPush change detection](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html).

There is a lot of more advanced topics in this answer, so I suggest you google/read the links I posted.